# Is there a way to show multiple people assigned to a Deliverable/Task WIT, without using the Assigned To field or creating multiple WITs

Tags: azure-devops

I'm creating an Azure Board where I'm listing the tasks for the day. Very often multiple people are working on one task at the day. I know that I cannot assign multiple people to a WIT, so I wanted to ask if there's some other way to show multiple people that I'm assigning this task to.

[image: Image depicting an example Work Item on the board]

I'm currently using Assigned To for the person that is doing the Task, and PMOwner as the Point of Contact for the Task, but I need multiple people working on the task.

**Creating multiple WITs won't work**, because the board will get absurdly cluttered with the amount of duplicate tasks that will be there.

Note that my permissions won't let me do any process inheritance or other actions that are as invasive.

Answer (score 0):

Process inheritance is the way to go here if you want to use in-the-box features. You could add additional Identity based fields to the process.

[image: Add a field of type identity to the work item]

Other than process changes, you could look at extensions to group work together.  The multi-value work item control would have been an option, but that too requires changes to the work item process.

And you could use the Tags feature and have a tag for each person and show that on the card.

Comment: Yeah, I can't modify or inherit the process, as this is out of my permissions scope, and out of my reach as the organization administrator insists on operating only on the default Scrum one.

I'll try out the Tags feature, but I'll leave the discussion open if maybe others have some other interesting ideas.

Thank you :)